# Does TinyMCE image insert plugin have a way to see thumbnail preview?

Tags: image, tinymce, thumbnails, tinymce-4

I currently have tinymce 4.9.4.

It has a image insert plugin that allows me to load a local list of images and select from them with a dropdown. The dropdown isn't very usable as it shows no thumbnails or previews of the image that will be inserted, only the name.

Some people are saying there is an option that enables this but i can't find the documentation.

https://community.tiny.cloud/communityQuestion?id=90661000000MrkqAAC

Another option would be to find a different image insert plugin but having trouble finding one that isn't subscription based.